# doFilter called twice - How to control this behaviour or any work around to fix the issue?

Tags: spring

I am having issues due to the doFilter running multiple times.
Expected logic - Return ABC.com when the logout flag is true and
Return XYZ.com when the logout flag is false

First call to doFilter invokes getRedirectUrl(true) which returns the expected url, but the second and third call to doFilter invokes getRedirectUrl(false) which returns incorrect result. I was looking to use OncePerRequestFilter but as the AuthFilter extends a class already I might not be able to use it. Can someone help me to resolve this issue please?

```
   @Controller
    @Validated
    public class TestController extends BaseController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE })
        public String logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
                session.setAttribute(LOGOUT, true); //logout flag set here to drive the filter logic
                //calltofilter();
            return logoutUrl;
        }
    }

    @Service
    public class AuthFilter extends SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter {
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
            if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
                if (authentication == null) {
                    if (SomeCondition) {
                        doSomethingA();
                    } else {
                        doSomethingB();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

        void doSomethingB(String authority, HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse)
                throws IOException {
            httpResponse.setStatus(302);
            boolean logout = Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(session.getAttribute(LOGOUT))); // The Logout flag is true
                                                                                            // here
            String redirectUrl = getRedirectUrl(logout);
            session.setAttribute(LOGOUT, false); // The Logout flag is set to false here because I dont need it after
                                                    // one execution
            httpResponse.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);

        }

        String getRedirectUrl(boolean logout) throws MalformedURLException {
            if (logout) {
                returnUrl = "ABC.com"; // I want this block to be executed
            } else {
                returnUrl = "XYZ.com";
            }
            return returnUrl;
        }
```

Comment: Because it is a filter spring boot automatically registers it, you probably also register it as a spring security filter, executing it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to **not** add your filter to spring security filter chain or register it via `FilterRegistrationBean`. Quoting Spring Spring:

> Be careful when you declare your filter as a Spring bean, either by annotating it with @Component or by declaring it as a bean in your configuration, because Spring Boot will automatically register it with the embedded container. That may cause the filter to be invoked twice, once by the container and once by Spring Security and in a different order.

> If you still want to declare your filter as a Spring bean to take advantage of dependency injection for example, and avoid the duplicate invocation, you can tell Spring Boot to not register it with the container by declaring a FilterRegistrationBean bean and setting its enabled property to false:

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#adding-custom-filter) is the spring security documentations.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<TenantFilter> tenantFilterRegistration(TenantFilter  filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean<TenantFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: Just inject the filter instead of creating it manually, which is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: If it is annotated with any of stereotype annotation, won't boot detect and add them to the chain again twice ?

Comment: Not if for the same filter there is a `FilterRegistrationBean`.

Comment: Got it. I will update my answer accordingly. `FilterRegistrationBean` would only disable the filter registered with MVC not the one with security.

Comment: Exactly, you set it to `disabled` and then can use the created filter to applyh in the security filter chain.

Comment: Thank you. Learnt something new. I have updated my answer accordingly.